# Download synchronous with nodejs

Tags: node.js, download, synchronous

Currently I am using a npm package called [download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download) to download files. I am looping through an array of links to download with a forEach and the download is being triggered within the loop. The problem I am having is when the array of links to download is quite big, the files aren't completely being downloaded. I think this is happening because I am downloading so many files asynchronously. So now I am trying to do this synchronously, but I can't seem to find how to do this. In the snippet below I am only showing the relevant code that is needed for my problem.

```
arrayLinks.forEach(function(link){
    new download({mode: "755"}).get(link).rename(title).dest(directory).use(downloadStatus()).run();                    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to write it in a function and use the callback function of [run()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download#runcallback) to fetch the next file from the huge file list.

```
function loadFiles(fileList){

    if(fileList instanceof Array && fileList.length > 0){

        new download({
                mode:"755"
            })
            .get(fileList.splice(0,1)[0]) // Fetches the first element from array 
            .rename(title)
            .dest(directory)
            .use(downloadStatus())
            .run(function(){
                loadFiles(fileList);
            });

    }else{
       console.log('job done');
    }
}

loadFiles(originFileList);
```

When you want to run multiple downloads the function can be called in a loop and give them all the same fileList.

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i+=1){
    loadFiles(originFileList); // Will run 10 downloads in parallel until fileList is empty.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help @Bernhard. But it seems it is still downloading it synchronously. I tried debugging it a bit and it seems your code should be working but it's still downloading multiple files at the same time. And I didn't use your suggestion for the for loop. Also the problem I originally had is still occurring; files not being downloaded completely. Also in the console I can see the downloadstatus plugin that is being used and it's also indicating that not everything is 100% downloaded. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @mXX if you put a ``console.log('test')``behind the ``loadFiles(originFileList);`` call and the message is written in terminal before the file is downloaded completely it's async. To verify if the downloading package works properly add also some log message into the callback. if you see this log message once the download is completed the callback is also working well.

Comment: The message is written in the terminal before the file being downloaded and also the log inside the callback is being printed multiple times. So I'm still able to download synchronous. Do you have other suggestions, how I can implement this to be synchronous? Thanks for your help so far @Bernhard